# What happens to an unusable index after table is truncated?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, indexing, truncate

In Oracle 11g, if an index is made unusable and the table gets truncated, what will happen to the unusable index? What will be its status ?

Comment: On truncate the entire table statistics are updated and unusable index gets usable(valid).

Comment: Here is the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10007.htm#SQLRF01707) to documentation.